# bizarre routing error though available in rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-resources

i have

```
<li><%= link_to "Messages", user_messages_path %></li>
```

in my routes.rb i have

```
  resources :users do
    resources :messages
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
```

when i do rake routes, it says....

```
user_messages GET    /users/:user_id/messages(.:format)      messages#index
```

the error is weird because if i add the list item tag on my _header partial in the layouts folder, visiting even my root page gives the error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"messages"}
```

however if i visit the url

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1/messages
```

im able to see the page. i do have a controller named messages_controller.rb also.

does anyone have an idea whats wrong? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give a user to `user_messages_path`, like

```
<li><%= link_to "Messages", user_messages_path(@user) %></li>
```